# Call Lisp Code from R?

Tags: r, lisp, common-lisp

Is there any way to connect R to Lisp? I have alogrithms written in Lisp but other part of my work is in R and I wanted to automate the entire process. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: See https://common-lisp.net/project/rcl/ (I never used it, btw)

Comment: If there isn't much data transfer involved, you can use sockets for your IPC.

Comment: There is currently no method of calling lisp (functions) from R unless you go through C. The RCL project - the comment above, does the reverse, it calls R from common lisp. Reading your description of the issue, it may be what you need but it is not a precise answer to your title question.